# Jenkins email-ext plugin not sending mail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I have Jenkins version 1.480.3 installed on my machine and Email-Extention Plugin 2.30.2.

Test mail from "Manage Jenkins" section works fine. When I add editable email notification to my jobs, I am not receiving it.

Also tried configuring "Triggers" in editable email notification advanced section. That also didn work. Console logs of build shows email has been triggered.

Can someone help me on how to debug this?

Comment: ugh this is a really buggy plugin for how popular it is

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At first you have to create a template http://url-to-jenkins/emailexttemplates/.
In the field **"Project Recipient List"** you can add some emails (comma separated).
You can also insert global variables (*Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global properties*) with:
`${ENV, var="PATH"}`
[image]

The **"Advanced Settings..."** option provides a trigger management, just add  "Recipient List" and now you should get some emails by Jenkins.

[image]

Comment: this is the correct answer, no need to downgrade email-ext plugin to 2.25

Comment: doesn't work if I add to "Project Recipient List" the email kind of - developers@lists.mycompany.com

Answer (score 7):

It appears that, in some version Extended E-mail Notification become own SMTP Server configuration.
So check your configuration under "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "Extended E-mail Notification" and make sure that fields "SMTP Server" and "    Default user E-mail suffix" are filled properly.

Make sure also that the configuration is consistent with "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> E-mail Notification.

**TL;DR**

Fill out fields "SMTP Server" and " Default user E-mail suffix" under "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "Extended E-mail Notification"

Comment: Another heads up: it's worth confirming that Gmail is not filtering out messages from Jenkins into your Spam folder! See some instructions on the [Gmail Support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9008?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Wasted few days.

Also tried to Downgrade the email-ext plugin to 2.25
but this Doesn't help.

Test mail sended, In Console Log was Sending email to: *mymail*
But stiil have no messages.

**I found** solution that help me....

I used gmail. So I Verifeid my gmail account via cellphone, than I fill Security Settings and gave **Access to my account from unreliable sources.**

Then I fill that mail into **Use SMTP Authentication** in Global Settings.

That worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have SSL enabled under SMTP Auth settings. For me, I was able to see a successful trigger, but email was never sent.

[image]

Comment: What can we do about the hashing of the saved password?

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to resolve this issue, I've implemented everything mentioned here, and didn't work for me, the solution that worked for me was to uninstall the plugin and install it again!

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the email-ext plugin to 2.25

Comment: Download .hpi file from this link - [link](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/email-ext/2.25/) . Uninstall existing plugin and install using .hpi file.

Comment: Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced -> Upload Plugin. Upload your .hpi file and restart jenkins.

Comment: checking if this issue is fixed in email ext plugin version 2.40.5?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. with 2.40.5

Comment: I'm having the same issue in 2.50.0

Comment: I'm having the same issue in 2.62

Comment: same issue in 2.66

Comment: I got exactly setting in Jenkins built-in email and extend email plugin. Former can send without error, but latter cannot send and pop `no auth mechs supported by server and client`. Issue is gone if I downgrade from 2.72 to 2.25. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot. But chrome was auto filling my SMTP Authentication password, so when I changed any setting and clicked save, the password would also be overwritten.

Hopefully I can save someone else a headache!

Answer (score 0):

Short Description of problem that I was facing:

> When I was sending test mail from  Manage Jenkins -> Configure System
>   -> E-mail Notification, I was able to successfully send and receive emails but there is no such option to test email in Extended E-mail
>   Notification tab
>
> While running a job, when I was sending email in post-build step via E-mail plugin, I was able to successfully send and receive emails but with same settings, I was getting following error on sending mail via Extended E-mail:

```
MessagingException message: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
```

I went almost crazy searching for resolution of this issue. 
I tried every resolution mentioned on this page but no success. I even tried downgrading the plugin to 2.25 but I was still getting error when sending email via Extended E-mail plugin. Everywhere on internet also the only solution mentioned to solve this problem was to "Allow less secure apps" and to check if credentials are valid, which in my case were valid since I was able to successfully send mail via normal email plugin.

After struggling for a few days, I finally found the silly thing that was causing this issue.
I had to type-in email ids into each and every box in:
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Extended E-mail Notification.
Copy-pasting email ids or domain names is causing this annoying and time taking issue. So, in case if you fall in such a situation, please make sure you have handwritten email ids in each column and not copy pasted.

Following configurations for "Extended E-mail Notification" worked for me:

```
Email Extension Plugin : 2.69
SMTP server : smtp.gmail.com
Default user E-mail suffix: <left this blank>
Enabled Use SMTP Authentication
User Name: <email id of account through which email is to be sent>
Password: <Password of account through which email is to be sent>
Advanced Email Properties : <left this blank>
Use SSL : Enabled
SMTP port: 465
Charset: UTF-8
```

Also, I had enabled less secure apps.

Hope this saves someone's time!!

Comment: Are you using your own email account? Are you bothered with the "from" field telling everyone that email is from you instead of from, for example, jenkins@company.com?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime after 2.66, if the From field is not set in the project, it doesn't seem to be falling back to the system email address. I believe this ticket is tracking the issue. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63522

Answer (score 0):

i performed the following action (after hours and hours of investigation)
and at the end it worked for me.

1. Unistalled the Extended mail plug in.
2. Deleted from .jenksins the plugIn (it remains also after Unistall).
3. Reinstalled the Extended mail plug In and enabled it.
4. Restart Jenkins.
5. In the Jenkins Configure System, in the Extended E-mail Notification section,
   I set a new credential access to my gmail account
   (also the previous credential stored were correct but i preferred to generate a
   new one with a different description).
6. And then... Finally afteer several time on this matter it works for me!.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Extended E-mail Notification` > `Enable Debug Mode` (selected). It will show you more logs in the Job Run Console section.

In my case, it showed me in the logs that credentials copied from regular `email-ext` (`AK_AWS_SES_CREDENTIALS/****** (Migrated from email-ext username/password)`) were not able to connect to AWS SES SMTP service.