# How to fix the extended email plugin error "An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins 2.11 version with extended email plugin (v 1.61). I have set the default triggers to "Always" and "Failure- Any". Using Blue ocean plugin a Jenkins file is created and used to run the job. The settings of the email plugin and jenkins file is attached. The problem is sometimes the jenkins is not able to send the email and logs an message "An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored" and sometimes it works fine. How do i fix it?[image] [image]

Comment: extended email plugin (v 1.61) is pretty old , can you try upgrading you plugin ? Another point , triggers can have their own email list / can use email list defined in parent section , when we specify content type as project , so check advanced sections of editable-email post build section

Comment: @prudviraj: Now somehow its fixed but not fully, jenkins is logging a msg that email is sent by i am not receiving it.

Comment: check you spam as well in some time and in addition to that my advise is to test email activity from global ( manage jenkins page ) , where you can test email noitfication by providing email ids, and check this answer from stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106160/jenkins-email-ext-plugin-not-sending-mail?rq=1)